# Phonegap application using bootstrap

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, phonegap-build

I have created HTML pages in bootstrap for different devices.
but phone-gap official site and other sites suggest that use "nodejs" for pages.

should i need to re-create HTML pages using "nodejs" or it will work for "bootstrap" in phonegap?

Answer (score 3):

I've just built an app with Bootstrap and it works brilliantly both on Android and ios. Do localize it though so you're not using network resources to fetch css every time your app loads. Download the latest bootstrap version and drop the two files below into the css and scripts directories in your PhoneGap www directory, and load them in this order.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to use nodejs with phonegap. Yes, you can use bootstrap but as the other answer says - use local files so your users don't need to fetch bootstrap over the net.

Comment: I am using localfiles for bootstrap.. Thanks. :)